# Use querySelector between slash

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

Here the point with a exemple :

```
<h2>        
  <a href="/car/bmw/?load=0&value=5fs4dfsdf45"> </a>
</h2>
```

I want my `querySelector` to only select "bmw".

I used it (below), but it's only select the end of the sentence and not the value between "/car/" and "?load"

```
document.querySelector('h2 > a[href$=]');
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `querySelector()` selects a DOM node, not a string. Also your HTML is invalid. Correct your HTML, show us an accurate representative sample of that HTML and explain what you're trying to do, showing the desired output.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ***=** instead:

```
document.querySelector('h2>a[href*=bmw]')
```

Comment: What do you think the problem is that you're answering with this code? (Genuinely, I have no idea what he's trying to do with the code in the question.)

Comment: It's Work ! Thanks for the tip, The "*" instead of "$" solve my problem.